# Get the path of a video thumbail by providing video path

Tags: java, android, picasso

I'm trying to get from android Media database the thumb path of a video stored in phone internal storage , so I can use that thumb path in picasso library.

Somebody had any good result with this ?

Or if somebody knows how to extract with picasso a thumb from a video , but i think is faster to get it from db.

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 2):

check out createVideoThumbnail() from the [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ThumbnailUtils.html#createVideoThumbnail%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

Comment: I'm using it but is slow in a custom list view and i have to put it in a thread.i was thinking to use a already stored thumb and not create myself

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it .
All i wanted to do was to have a fast listview ,and to do not create a video thumb but to use a already created one , so my list to be smoth

Android add to his database a thumb for the videos that are in storage .

They are small size (MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND) but  they can be resized without no problem.

I got the videos IDs using code :

```
String[] columns = {
    MediaStore.Video.Media._ID,
    MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE,
    MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA,
    MediaStore.Video.Media.ARTIST,
    MediaStore.Video.Media.MIME_TYPE,
    MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE,
    MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION,
    MediaStore.Images.Media.HEIGHT,
    MediaStore.Images.Media.WIDTH,
};

Cursor cursor = ctx.getContentResolver().query(uri, columns, where, whereVal, orderBy);
if (cursor.moveToFirst())
{
    do
    {
       // cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media._ID)) is a video id
      //save curent video id in singleton class for example
         Singleton.addVideoID(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media._ID)));

    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
cursor.close();
```

And latter in the

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

of the ListView adapter will retrive the videos id from singleton and display the thumb asociated with this video id like this:

```
                int videoID = Singleton.getVideoID( position  );

                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
                        getActivity().getContentResolver(),
                        videoID,
                        MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND,
                        null );


                icon.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 120, 120, false));
```

icon is the ImageView where must be displayed the thumb ,and i scaled it to 120x120 to make it bigger .You must have the 'icon' defined in the xml of the adapter  layout mine is like this

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:maxHeight="120dp" 
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:contentDescription=""
    android:textColor="#000000"
     />
```

And the listview is smoth scrooling cause it do not create thumbs in getview , it just get the already created one and all is fast.You can control size too , if you want to change it.
I hope this help ppls who want to display thumbs in grid and lists and run smoth and fast.